# How to perform a bulk insert with Riak?

Tags: ruby, riak

How do I insert millions keys into a Riak bucket?

Inserting them one at a time takes too long.

Ideally I'd like something like MySQL's "LOAD DATA INFILE".

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK riak does not have bulk insert mode. you can increase the performance by using the protobuffer protocol.

reading the readme here https://github.com/basho/riak-ruby-client also indicates that map types support `batch` operations.